# API for turn-based multiplayer game

Tags: android, multiplayer

I would like to add the multiplayer functionality to my Android game. In particular it must be turn-based. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so i need a framework/API or whatever that avoid to write the server side. It is just a personal project of mine, so i have not special requirements. Now, i know 3 possibilities:

1. Google Play Services API for Turn-Based game
2. SmartFoxServer
3. Parse

I would like to know if there are other technologies or if any of the ones that i've written above is good.

Comment: As much as I love Parse, for ease of use go with what Google has to offer for Google Play Services

Comment: Is it free and actually used? Why it is worth to use?

Comment: google play services is cross platform with iOS and I'm sure you'll find a lot more tutorials

Comment: Google is ending the support for the Google Play Game Services Multiplayer API: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9469745
Seems they now want us to switch to Google Cloud or Firebase, where you have to pay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer

As someone said in comments, Google Play services is cross-platform and will work for iOS if you ported it in that direction. Also, the support in the way of tutorials and documentation is very great for this.

On top of that, you can integrate other Google goodies like high scores, badges, etc.

Comment: Ok you convinced me. Thank you!

Comment: Google Play services has an announcement now: `Google Play games services for iOS is deprecated, and is not likely to function as expected. Do not use Google Play games services for iOS in new apps. See the deprecation announcement blog post for more details.`

Comment: http 404 for the link posted.
as @Fer quoted, is deprecated, so, they're recommending firebase realtime database, a nosql general solution for modeling the turn base strategy, and open match, a paid approach for gcp. 

details: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9469745